# how to delete unnecessary <div> in python while extracting the text

Tags: python

I am doing work on extracting the text from web pages dynamically but i got stucked in get riding from lower div or lower portion of the pages (that contains e.g " ASP.NET | jQuery | AJAX | ANT | JSP | Servlets | log4j | iBATIS | Hibernate | JDBC | Struts | HTML5 | SQL | MySQL | C++ | UNIX
Copyright © 2014 by tutorialspoint. All Rights Reserved..").

I am extracting the required relevant text of "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/index.htm" and problem is that it also extracting the text which is at bottom or other way around as i expressed above. i tried to use array so that i can skip all such things. i successfully get rid from other links but failed here. my code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/index.htm"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style","a","<div id="bottom" ">): # "<div id="bottom" is it correct?? or whats the correct way?
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print text
```

and the output:

```
C++ Tutorial
|
|
|
C++ Basics
C++ Object Oriented
C++ Advanced
C++ Useful Resources
Selected Reading
C++ Tutorial
C++ is a middle-level programming language developed by Bjarne Stroustrup starting in 1979 at Bell Labs. C++ runs on a variety of platforms, such as Windows, Mac OS, and the various versions of UNIX.
This reference will take you through simple and practical approach while learning C++ Programming language.
Audience
This reference has been prepared for the beginners to help them understand the basic to advanced concepts related to C++ Programming languages.
Prerequisites
Before you start doing practice with various types of examples given in this reference, I'm making an assumption that you are already aware about what is a computer program and what is a computer programming language?
Compile/Execute C++ Programs
For most of the examples given in this tutorial, you will find Try it option to compile and execute C++ programs online, so just make use of it and enjoy your learning.
Try the following example using Try it option available at the top right corner of the below sample code box:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "Hello World";
return 0;
}
(1) C++ Basic Object Oriented Concepts
Just go through these concepts to understand basic Object Oriented Terminology.
(2) C++ Quick Guide
A quick C++ reference guide for C++ Programmers.
(3) C++ Useful Resources
A collection of C++ Sites, Books and Articles is given at this page.
(4) C++ References
A link on C++ Standard Library
(5) C Tutorial
Learn C in really simple steps with examples using this tutorial.
(6) C++ Tutorial in PDF
Download a quick C++ tutorial in PDF format.
Advertisements
Advertisements
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
Copyright © 2014 by tutorialspoint. All Rights Reserved.
```

Any other suggestion in skipping those "|" , "Copyright......" tag is appreciable !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, [css selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) should help you:

```
text = soup.select('.content')[0].get_text()
```

Comment: thanks it worked,  but is it also for other version of pages? bcz when place the link of "cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/"; it gave me error:  "Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\data extraction.py", line 13, in <module> text = soup.select('.content')[0].get_text() IndexError: list index out of range" –  giantmalik just now   edit

Comment: My solution should be tuned for each concrete page's html. Selector should be different for page on cpluplus.com: `.select('.C_doc')`. It's ok if you are scrapinh limited set of sites. If you want some generic solution that will find relevant content within _any_ markup, well... It's rather complicated task. Probably this article will help you: http://w-shadow.com/blog/2008/01/25/extracting-the-main-content-from-a-webpage/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but if the problem is this line:

```
for script in soup(["script", "style","a","<div id="bottom" ">):
```

Then there's an easy fix as that is not valid Python. Escape the double quotes in side a string like so, and place the final double quote in the right place:

```
for script in soup(["script", "style","a","<div id=\"bottom\" >"]):
```

Are you not using an editor with syntax highlighting? It should point out these kinds of errors to you.

Comment: thanks. i am trying to get only relevant text if u got to that web site which i have placed the link u will understand easily. i just want to extract reading material.